# implementing right / left swipe on listview

Tags: android, listview

I want to implement left / right swipe on list view to perform some operation e.g. delete etc. I've a code which i understood completely. It recognise all swipe gesture and Toast me when i swipe on screen.

The problem is I don't know how to implement this gesture to list view. I am in learning stage. Kindly guide me to implement swipe with my code because it'll easy for me to understand.

SimpleGestureFilter.java

```
package com.example.zohaibsiddique.gesture;

/**
 * Created by Zohaib Siddique on 29/06/2016.
 */
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class SimpleGestureFilter extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    public final static int SWIPE_UP = 1;
    public final static int SWIPE_DOWN = 2;
    public final static int SWIPE_LEFT = 3;
    public final static int SWIPE_RIGHT = 4;

    public final static int MODE_TRANSPARENT = 0;
    public final static int MODE_SOLID = 1;
    public final static int MODE_DYNAMIC = 2;

    private final static int ACTION_FAKE = -13; //just an unlikely number
    private int swipe_Min_Distance = 100;
    private int swipe_Max_Distance = 350;
    private int swipe_Min_Velocity = 100;

    private int mode = MODE_DYNAMIC;
    private boolean running = true;
    private boolean tapIndicator = false;

    private Activity context;
    private GestureDetector detector;
    private SimpleGestureListener listener;

    public SimpleGestureFilter(Activity context, SimpleGestureListener sgl) {

        this.context = context;
        this.detector = new GestureDetector(context, this);
        this.listener = sgl;
    }

    public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if (!this.running)
            return;

        boolean result = this.detector.onTouchEvent(event);

        if (this.mode == MODE_SOLID)
            event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
        else if (this.mode == MODE_DYNAMIC) {

            if (event.getAction() == ACTION_FAKE)
                event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
            else if (result)
                event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
            else if (this.tapIndicator) {
                event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
                this.tapIndicator = false;
            }

        }
        //else just do nothing, it's Transparent
    }

    public void setMode(int m) {
        this.mode = m;
    }

    public int getMode() {
        return this.mode;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean status) {
        this.running = status;
    }

    public void setSwipeMaxDistance(int distance) {
        this.swipe_Max_Distance = distance;
    }

    public void setSwipeMinDistance(int distance) {
        this.swipe_Min_Distance = distance;
    }

    public void setSwipeMinVelocity(int distance) {
        this.swipe_Min_Velocity = distance;
    }

    public int getSwipeMaxDistance() {
        return this.swipe_Max_Distance;
    }

    public int getSwipeMinDistance() {
        return this.swipe_Min_Distance;
    }

    public int getSwipeMinVelocity() {
        return this.swipe_Min_Velocity;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                           float velocityY) {

        final float xDistance = Math.abs(e1.getX() - e2.getX());
        final float yDistance = Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY());

        if (xDistance > this.swipe_Max_Distance || yDistance > this.swipe_Max_Distance)
            return false;

        velocityX = Math.abs(velocityX);
        velocityY = Math.abs(velocityY);
        boolean result = false;

        if (velocityX > this.swipe_Min_Velocity && xDistance > this.swipe_Min_Distance) {
            if (e1.getX() > e2.getX()) // right to left
                this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_LEFT);
            else
                this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_RIGHT);

            result = true;
        } else if (velocityY > this.swipe_Min_Velocity && yDistance > this.swipe_Min_Distance) {
            if (e1.getY() > e2.getY()) // bottom to up
                this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_UP);
            else
                this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_DOWN);

            result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        this.tapIndicator = true;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent arg) {
        this.listener.onDoubleTap();
        ;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent arg) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent arg) {

        if (this.mode == MODE_DYNAMIC) {        // we owe an ACTION_UP, so we fake an
            arg.setAction(ACTION_FAKE);      //action which will be converted to an ACTION_UP later.
            this.context.dispatchTouchEvent(arg);
        }

        return false;
    }

    static interface SimpleGestureListener {
        void onSwipe(int direction);

        void onDoubleTap();
    }
}
```

SwipeScreenExample.java

```
package com.example.zohaibsiddique.gesture;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.zohaibsiddique.gesture.SimpleGestureFilter.SimpleGestureListener;

public class SwipeScreenExample extends AppCompatActivity implements SimpleGestureListener{

    private SimpleGestureFilter detector;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Detect touched area
        detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this,this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){
        // Call onTouchEvent of SimpleGestureFilter class
        this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipe(int direction) {
        String str = "";

        switch (direction) {

            case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT : str = "Swipe Right";
                break;
            case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT :  str = "Swipe Left";
                break;
            case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_DOWN :  str = "Swipe Down";
                break;
            case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_UP :    str = "Swipe Up";
                break;

        }
        Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDoubleTap() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Double Tap", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is this project on Github and it implements RecyclerView

#### https://github.com/nikhilpanju/RecyclerViewEnhanced

Comment: its not much helpful because its not have swipe functionality implemented which i need.

Comment: Just elaborate your requirements and i will look into it.

Comment: as my question i want to implement this swipe gesture to any listview to delete an item.

Answer (score 1):

> In order to implement swipe in your listView or RecyclerView, I would suggest "AndroidSwipeLayout" project.

Visit https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout for download and how to use.

hope it will help you :)